# Can the results about quadratic forms be generalized to arbitary polynomials of degree $2$?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations

I came across two theorems dealing with the question whether a quadratic form can represent every positive integer (Details here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_and_290_theorems )

But there are several restrictions. If I understand it correctly, the theorem can only be applied for homogenous polynomials of degree $2$. Moreover, the quadratic form must be positive definite.

> Can the theorems be generalized to arbitary polynmials of degree $2$ ?

In other words, can we determine, whether an equation like $$x^2-xy+y^2-2yz+2z^2-3x+5y+6z-8=n$$  has an integer solution for all positive integers $n$ ?

I do not require to find all solutions or to decide whether there are solutions at all. It would be sufficient to find an $n$ for which there is no solution or to show that there is a solution for every $n$.

Comment: Such quadratic forms are endless. A similar task there. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263153/indefinite-quadratic-form-universal-over-negative-integers/263240#263240  Here it is necessary to act similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the many questions in number theory which has a simple statement, but potentially a very difficult answer. At present it's not clear how to generalize the analytic machinery that makes things like the 290-theorem possible to prove. In particular, the theory of modular forms plays a key role here, and while it is still true that there is a modular form attached to a quadratic polynomial, there is no particularly nice formula for the contribution of the Eisenstein series.

I don't know off-hand a quadratic polynomial for which it's unknown whether it represents every positive integer, but it is quite difficult for Anna Haensch and Ben Kane to prove (in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06573)) that every sufficiently large positive integer is a sum of three $m$-gonal numbers if $m \not\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$ and $4 \nmid m$.

There are ternary quadratic forms whose representation behavior we do not yet understand. In particular, it is not known whether every odd number can be written in the form $x^{2} + xy + 5y^{2} + 2z^{2}$ (although I proved in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.0979) that it does, assuming the generalized Riemann hypothesis).